# React-Native 0.57 and Storybook compatibility issues

Tags: react-native, babeljs, storybook

I have been trying to get Storybook 3.4.4 to work with react 0.57.  I have recently upgraded from 0.55.4 where things seemed to be fine.

I have also upgraded to babel 7 using the babel-upgrade tool.

Now when i try to run my Storybook...

`storybook start -p 7007`

`react-native run-android`

i get the following error...

---

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

 Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApk'.

 A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-vector-icons'.

 Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':react-native-vector-icons:_debugPublishCopy'.

 Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1.
           Searched in the following locations:
               file:/Users/[XXX]/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.1.1/appcompat-v7-27.1.1.pom

file:/Users/[XXX]/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.1.1/appcompat-v7-27.1.1.jar

file:/Users/[MY PROJECT LOCATION]/android/sdk-manager/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/27.1.1/appcompat-v7-27.1.1.jar
           Required by:
               boilerplate:react-native-vector-icons:unspecified > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.57.0
Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 9.08 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
```

---

Can anyone help me out please?

Comment: You probably need to update your androidBuildTools, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39519515/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v7-24-0-1

Answer (score 0):

If `storybook start -p 7007` runs fine, the issue is not related to `babel` nor `storybook`.

From you stacktrace, your error must be coming from the `build.gradle` at the root of your project.

Make sure you have the right maven repository in your dependencies.

You should have a look at this issue: https://github.com/react-community/lottie-react-native/issues/343